# .htaccess File, path is redirected properly but images and css are not loaded

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

Hi I am using the following lines in my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /coaster/CoasterInsider/
 RewriteRule signup$ index.php?page=signup [L,NC]
 RewriteRule login$ index.php?page=loginHandle [L,NC]
 RewriteRule u/(.*)$ index.php?page=profile&username=$1 [L,NC]
```

The path is getting redirected properly, but the css,flash and images are not loading. Also if I use the following '/' after any url say,

```
RewriteRule signup(/?)$ index.php?page=signup [L,NC]
```

It's not finding any page there, i.e. error 404. I just want my htaccess file to work for both /signup and /signup/

Comment: With URL rewriting, you should use absolute paths for images/css/javascript/etc. Can you post example URLs of the page and the paths  of CSS/Images etc.

Comment: I'm using the paths like <img src="site/images/photo.png" /> Is it wrong? because that's not working

Comment: yes, use complete url i.e. http://localhost/mysite/images/img.jpg

Comment: Do you have an actual folder `/site/images/`?

Comment: Yes i've actual folder, I'm testing it locally in a subdirectory under www folder named coaster/CoasterInsider/, and the images resides under www/coaster/CoasterInsider/images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When browser displays:

```
http://example.com/coaster/CoasterInsider/signup
http://example.com/coaster/CoasterInsider/signup/
```

and encounters a relative URL such as:

```
<img src="site/images/photo.png">
```

It translates the relative URL to (respectively):

```
http://example.com/coaster/CoasterInsider/site/images/photo.png
http://example.com/coaster/CoasterInsider/signup/site/images/photo.png
```

You should use absolute URLs for assets. Make this a habit:

```
<img src="/site/images/photo.png">
```

Alternately you can use the HTML [`base`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.4) tag in your pages which tells browsers how to treat relative URLs. Personally I do not recommend it.

Comment: Is there any way to redirect the requests for images using htaccess, or we can redirect the requests for http://example.com/coaster/CoasterInsider/signup/ to http://example.com/coaster/CoasterInsider/images/image.png ?

Comment: Do you have separate image directories for each page (or set of pages)?

Comment: No I have a single directory for all of the pages.

Comment: For _many_ images, you can add a base tag in your pages inside the `<head>` section; this could have side effects so keep an eye on 404 errors. I still recommend doing a brutal find/replace to change relative URLs to absolute.

Comment: If something like this could work..     RewriteRule signup/(.*)(\.css)$ site/css/$1.css

Comment: Rule looks OK except you need a leading `/` in the replacement: `RewriteRule signup/(.*)(\.css)$ /site/css/$1.css`. Again, this is also bad. Browsers will download separate copy of same CSS.

Comment: Hey the above worked, can we have a rule like this     RewriteRule signup/(.*)(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif)$ $1.$2

Comment: Thanks for help, the ultimate answer is use the absolute links or any other solution is there? Although currently I have stick to absolute paths but will be great if any other solution within htaccess can be found.

Answer (score 1):

This was advised to, and worked for me, place it inside the `<head>` tags in your `html`: `<base href="/">` Again, it worked for me, I hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

to exclude real files and directories from being rewritten.

You could also add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

to do the same for symlinks.

Comment: I've added all of the three lines, just below RewriteBase but still not loading, if it has to do something with sub directory?